# Android: error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: java, android, xml

There's an error in my activity_main.xml on line 13 (Wich you can see below). It says "Error parsing XML: not well-formed(invalid token)". In addition to that my R.java has killed itself. I've found ways to fix it, but they won't work (At least I think it's because of that) until this error is fixed. **Thanks for any help**. Just by the way I'm following the tutorial on [Javacodegeeks.com](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-tutorial-and-basic-example.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:mynamespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.Learning.learning"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            mynamespace:layout_width="success"
            mynamespace:orientation="vertical"
            mynamespace:layout_height="success">

            <ListView   android:id="@+id/listView"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

                    List<Map<String>> planetsList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>() />

                        private void initList() {
                            //we populate them Planets

                            planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Mercury"));
                            planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Venus"));
                            planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Earth"));
                            planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Mars"));
                            planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Jupiter"));
                            planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Saturn"));
                            planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Uranus"));
                            planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Neptune"));
                        }

                        private HashMap<String, String> createPlanet(String key, String name) {
                            HashMap<String, String> planet = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            planet.put(key, name);

                            return planet;
                        }

                        // This is a simple adapter that accepts as parameter
                        // Context
                        // Data List
                        // The row layout that is used during the row creation
                        // The keys used to retrieve the data
                        // The View id used to show the data. The number and the view must match
                        simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(this, planetsList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String []
                        {"planet"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

                    </ListView>
```

Comment: I see just 11 lines of XML. Where is line 13? Or did you really write the program code into the xml file?

Comment: You can't put java code inside XML file.

Comment: yes I did... Sorry I'm a complete newb

Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you mixed the Java code in the activity_main.xml too? 
Because your activity_main.xml should only contain the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView android:id="@+id/listView" 
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And MainActivity.java should contain the following code:

```
List<Map<String, String>> planetsList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

private void initList() {

planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Mercury"));
planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Venus"));
planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Mars"));
planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Jupiter"));
planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Saturn"));
planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Uranus"));
planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Neptune"));

}

private HashMap<String, String> createPlanet(String key, String name) {
HashMap<String, String> planet = new HashMap<String, String>();
planet.put(key, name);

return planet;
}
```

I have just copied the code here from the link that you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your JavaCode from xml and put it in seperate java file you cannot put java code inside your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting Java code inside the XML file? Java code goes inside a class file.

According to that tutorial, they want you to create a xml file called `activity_main.xml`
with contents

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView" 
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And separatelly, a java class called `MainActivity.java`

with contents

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       // ....
    }
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from your posted link [source](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-tutorial-and-basic-example.html)

Remove Javacode inside XML tags

**And**

I think change it as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:mynamespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.Learning.learning"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            mynamespace:layout_width="success"
            mynamespace:orientation="vertical"
            mynamespace:layout_height="success">

            <ListView   android:id="@+id/listView"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent" /> 
</RelativeLayout>                                           ^Listview tag closed here
```

Remove `</ListView>` tag. Because you are already closed at 12th line

Answer (score 0):

You have included java code in the XML file. 
Remember that Android uses XML files for layouts and resources definition only. 
Code for data poplulation, manipulation and other processing must be done in the java source files. For example, you can populate the list within you MainActivity.java file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write your program code in your XML file. That is why you have an error. Read more about [XML Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)